# "use_2to3 is invalid" when installing pybluez package

Tags: python, installation, pip, pybluez

I got this error:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: `use_2to3 is invalid` maybe this is because you are using Python 2 instead of 3 or viceversa? Have you tried running `pip3 install pybluez`  ?

Comment: i'm using python 3.7 with pip 23.0

Comment: Sometimes `pip` from command line calls python 2 instead of 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error+in+setup+command%3A+use_2to3+is+invalid